# Find $a,b$ and $c$ such that $(-4b+4c)\cos(2x)+(-4c-4b-4)\sin(2x)=3-2a.$

Tags: trigonometry

I want to find $a,b$ and $c$ such that
$$(-4b+4c)\cos(2x)+(-4c-4b-4)\sin(2x)=3-2a.$$

I think if $3-2a=0$, then we can easily find them.

Comment: I think writing $a\cos(2x)+b\sin(2x)$ as $A\cos(2x+\alpha)$ may help.

Comment: Is this meant to be true for all values of $x$? In which case you would need the coefficients of sin and cos both to be zero, and also $3-2a=0$

Comment: @DavidQuinn Yes for all $x$

Comment: So you can finish this, right?